# Android регистрация и авторизация

Tags: java, android, json, post

Есть сайт [сайтвотутта][1]
(сразу извиняюсь за такое название сайта) На данной странице как вы уже поняли ссылка на регистрацию на сайте. Мне необходимо сделать мобильное приложение под android, а именно форму регистрации и авторизации. Как это делать ?

Нужно использовать метод Post ,а форматы запросов вида Json.Посмотря Youtube и т.д понял что ничего не сделаю без чьей либо помощи.

Пробовал сделать сам но без успешно.

```
EditText etEmail, etPassword;
TextView tvRegister;
Button btnLogin;

final String url_Login = "https://balodaizaiti.000webhostapp.com/register_user.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    tvRegister = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_register);


    tvRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String Email = etEmail.getText().toString();
            String Password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            new LoginUser().execute(Email, Password);
        }
    });
}




public class LoginUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String Email = strings[0];
        String Password = strings[1];

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("user_id", Email)
                .add("user_password", Password)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url_Login)
                .post(formBody)
                .build();

        Response response = null;
        try{
            response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                String result = response.body().string();
                if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("login")){
                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                            DashboardActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }else{
                   showToast("Email or Password mismatched!");
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}



public void showToast(final String Text){
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                    Text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: ссылку оформите (для ссылок есть специальная кнопка), расставьте пробелы/знаки препинания и приложите код.

Comment: Попробуй использовать библеотку Retrofit 2
<https://habr.com/ru/post/314028/>